# How to force user to document a class member in Visual Studio for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a configuration in Visual Studio to force user to document new added methods?

I'm expecting it to work like when **language version** is defined in **Advanced Building Settings** for example if you define language version to be C# 5 you won't be handle to use C# 6 feature, the project will refuse to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

In the project properties, go to Build - 'Output' - check the 'XML documentation file'.

Then, above that, set `Treat warnings as errors` to `Specific warnings` and enter `CS1591`.

The project will fail to compile when public members are not documented.

[image: See code]

Comment: @IvandroIsmael You're welcome. If the answer is working for you, please consider marking it as accepted.